# What is the verb or phrasal verb do describe the action when someone persistently wants to be friends with someone especially when they aren't wanted?

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

What is the verb or phrasal verb do describe someone's action when they persistently wan to be friends with someone especially when they aren't wanted and welcom and their behaviour isn't of sexual nature? They just want to hang out with someone for unknown reasons. Does *force onself onto* someone sound natural? For example:

> That guy is such creep. He is always **forcing** himself **onto** me.

Comment: Not quite what you were requesting, but *pushy* (adjective) and *won't take no for an answer* (phrase) come to mind.

Comment: "Force onto" as in your example sounds like you are being sexually assaulted. I definitely would avoid that choice of words.

Comment: You are asking for a verb to “describe someone”, but remember that an adjective describes someone (or something).  The verb or phrasal verb you want describes the action taken by the person, not the person themselves.

Comment: We need the context explained some more please. You say “wants to be friends” which suggest the person wants simple friendship. But then you use “creep” and “forcing himself onto me” that seem to suggest something sexual, with another suggestion that his behavior is somewhere in a range from very pushy to assault (as @TypeIA suggests).  What is this person after - friendship or a sexual relationship?  If it’s sexual, do you really mean to suggest he is aggressive or abusive, or do you just mean his advances are well behaved but repeated without him realizing he is not welcome?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/

Comment: puppetstck: thanks, very "helpful"